# Sort by insertion sort [descending]

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

if this code is to sort by ascending

```
    public static String [] selectionSort_String(String[] inList) {
   String temp;     


   for (int i=0; i<(inList.length-1); i++) {
       for (int j=i+1; j<inList.length; j++) {
           if (inList[i].compareTo(inList[j]) > 0) {
               temp = inList[i];
               inList[i] = inList[j];
               inList[j] = temp;
           }
       }
   }

   // return the sorted Array
   return inList;
```

How Do I get it to Sort by descending?

Comment: `if(inList[i].compareTo(inList[j]) < 0)`

Comment: Either the title of the question or the name of your function is wrong. Selection sort != insertion sort

Comment: There are dozens of implemented sorting algorithms in Java.
Why not try to search?
Here is the first link from the google:
http://mathbits.com/MathBits/Java/arrays/InsertionSort.htm

Comment: As a cute trick - you could always just sort it normally and then reverse the array at the end. :-)

Comment: @templatetypedef While this would work, it would be less efficient than sorting it in descending order in the first place unless there was a need to have it sorted in ascending order first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is incredibly trivial. In your algorithm, you swap indicies `i` and `j` if `inList[i]` has a larger value than `inList[j]`. Simply change the boolean logic when you swap them (i.e. i is smaller than j).

```
...
for (int i=0; i<(inList.length-1); i++) {
   for (int j=i+1; j<inList.length; j++) {
       if (inList[i].compareTo(inList[j]) < 0) { // <--Changing the operator to LT
           temp = inList[i];
           inList[i] = inList[j];
           inList[j] = temp;
       }
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

The absolute easiest way to change the direction of the sort here, is to change the if-statement operator > to <.

```
if (inList[i].compareTo(inList[j]) < 0) {
```

You can have a look here to see how compareTo works
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 1):

Just switch > with < in the compareTo line.

Answer (score 0):

You can sort using Arrays.sort and on the implementation compare object2 with object1 to invert the result.

```
Comparator<String> comparator = new Comparator<String>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
                return o2.compareTo(o1);
            }
        };

Arrays.sort(strings, comparator);
```